# Animation Effectiveness

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
for button in buttonGroup {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        button.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

VS

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        for button in buttonGroup {
            button.alpha = 0
        }
    })
```

I have more than 40 buttons in `buttonGroup`,could be more later, I wonder which way is better?
The standard is resource consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously Second one. Because in case of first the `UIView.animateWithDuration` is called many (total button in buttonGroup) times. This is not efficient programming and also animation become choppy. But in case of second one `UIView.animateWithDuration` called only one time and accomplished the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the performance of a block of code in xcodes unit test class and measure the speed of each. Create a Unit test framework and the method you need will be there in the template.

Are all your buttons in the same superview? If so consider embedding them in their own `UIView` and simply adjusting the alpha on that single view instead of all your `UIButtons`.

Comment: New to IOS and it's a time-budget project. Definitely Unit Test later. And thank your group-buttons-by-single-view advice, never think of that before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write some Unit tests. just take a look at xCode debug navigator (shortcut: cmd + 6), look at app's CPU and memory, compare it. Or maybe you can use instruments to compare it. Personally i prefer the second one. (agree with @Md.Muzahidul Islam)